# Python dict from mobypos.txt file

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

I have a file from the [Moby Project](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moby_Project) that pairs words with one or more letters indicating their part of speech. For example:

```
hemoglobin\N
hemogram\N
hemoid\A
hemolysin\N
hemolysis\N
hemolytic\A
hemophile\NA
hemophiliac\N
```

Hemoglobin is a noun, hemoid is an adjective, and hemophile can be used as a noun or an adjective.

I have created a dict from this file that pairs a word with the letters indicating its part of speech using the following code:

```
mm = open("mobypos.txt").readlines()
pairs = []
for x in mm:
    pairs.append(x.split("\\"))
posdict = dict(pairs)
```

This works successfully. What I want to do is generate lists called `nouns`, `verbs`, `adjectives`, etc that contain all the words of this part of speech. What is the fastest way to do this, given that `len(posdict.keys())` returns `233340`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension

```
nouns = [word, type in posdict.iteritems() if 'N' in type]

adjs = [word, type in posdict.iteritems() if 'A' in type]

verbs = [word, type in posdict.iteritems() if 'V' in type]
```

The use of the `in` operator in the `if` clause will place words with multiple types accordingly.

Comment: Why do I want to use `iteritems` instead of `items`? Is it faster?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator expression to get an iterator of relative words :

```
nouns = (w for w,type in posdict.iteritems() if type=='N')
```

But note that since iterators are one shot iterables , when you just want to iterate over them and don't want to get the specific items or use some functions like `len` its better to use them, which are very optimized in terms of memory use. but if you want to use them a lot of times you better to use a list comprehension.

```
nouns = [w for w,type in posdict.iteritems() if type=='N']
```

Comment: Why do I want to use `iteritems` instead of `items`? Is it faster?